# How are "Macrometers" officially called?

Tags: transformer, meter, metering

I have been doing research about the name of these electric meters. I found a rough definition of it, but i have been told the name is not right.

the definition goes as follow:

"Macrometers are meters that perform a function similar to customer meters, but are attached to a public distribution transformer that feeds a secondary network.

These measurement equipment allow a comparison to be made between the total energy registered at the transformer terminals, with respect to the sum of the energy registered from the meters of the electrical services connected to that transformer, facilitating what is known as a Low voltage energy balance. The difference between the two values ​​is known as energy loss."

I would like to know the specific name of the mentioned meter.

Comment: I haven't heard a specific term for this, and had not heard "macrometer" used before. 
I found the abstract to [this IEEE paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6281652)  giving the alternate name of "communal meters" which I would prefer.

Comment: "Transformer-rated meter" ?

Comment: So where was this macrometer definition written?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you may be talking about a [Distribution Transformer Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_Transformer_Monitor) (DTM).

This is a device that is attached to a distribution transformer to monitor various parameters such as voltage, current, and power, and serves a number of purposes, for example electricity theft detection, power outage detection, and generally monitoring performance aspects of the distribution system.

I am finding the term *macro meter* in some literature though, so when referring to a meter that simply measures power use for multiple end users *macro meter* might be the correct terminology.

[example of literature referencing term 'macro meter'](https://www.wilsoncenter.org/sites/default/files/media/documents/publication/CUSP_130604_Innovation%20in%20Urban%20Poverty_rpt%201106.pdf)